# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am building an encoder decoder model, but when I am trying to pass the weights I am getting above mentioned error. Here is my code in brief:

```
classes = [item for sublist in train_summary.tolist() for item in sublist]
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(classes), classes)
print(type(class_weights))
e_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4, verbose=1, mode='min', restore_best_weights=True)
history = seq2seq_model.fit(x=[train_article, train_summary], y=np.expand_dims(train_target, -1),
                            batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1,
                            callbacks=[e_stopping], class_weight=class_weights)
```

this is the error,

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model)
   1114     strategy = ds_context.get_strategy()
   1115     dataset = self._adapter.get_dataset()
-> 1116     if class_weight:
   1117       dataset = dataset.map(_make_class_weight_map_fn(class_weight))
   1118     self._inferred_steps = self._infer_steps(steps_per_epoch, dataset)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

I think that `data_adapter.py` file should be modified, `class_weights` is a numpy array and to check if this array is empty or not we have to use `np.any(array)`, but it seems that the python file in `keras` package is not doing this work.

Comment: if class_weights is an array of dim (train_size,) you have to pass it in sample_weight param and not in class_weight which accepts a dictionary object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: It seems that Keras requires a dictionary of weights as suggested in the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61261907/on-colab-class-weight-is-causing-a-valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-wit).